# In VMware how to create a shared folder between two guest operating system?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I have two guest os (mint, windows). How can I create a shared folder among them?

Comment: VMware ESXi, or Fusion/Workstation/Player? What's your networking setup, NAT, bridged, etc?

Comment: I have vmware work station and network NAT.

Comment: You should be able to use the VMware Tools Shared Folder option to share a folder on your host.  Go to the settings of the VM, Options, Shared Folders, enable it and add the folder on your host.  Do this on both VMs.  Linux, I think you'll need to reboot for the share to show up.  It should be in your Home folder.  Windows will give you an option to map a drive.